# Spring validation is not working even though the code looks fine

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I just started testing validation with javax.validation.constraints and i think i did everything well, but it's somehow not working. I'm looking at my code for so long now and can't find anything wrong with it. When i type wrong name data to form and submit, error text doesn't pop and (errors.hasErrors()) is false meaning there weren't any errors.

Here's my class:

```
@Data
public class Application {
    private int id;

    @NotNull(message = "Nazwa wymagana!")
    @Size(min=2, message = "Name should have at least 2 characters!")
    @Size(max=30, message = "Name too long!")
    private String name;

    private String domain;
    private List<Person> users;
}
```

Controller:

```
    @GetMapping("applications/new")
    public String addAppSetup(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("app", new Application());
        return "applications-add";
    }

    @PostMapping("/applications/add")
    public String addApp(@Valid Application app, Model model, Errors errors){
        if(errors.hasErrors()){
            return "applications-add";
        }
        applicationService.addApplication(app);
        model.addAttribute("apps", applicationService.getApplications());
        return "redirect:/applications";
    }
```

Form:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/applications/add}" th:object="${app}" method="post">
    <div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors()}">
          <span>
             Proszę popraw błędy i spróbuj ponownie.
          </span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="nameeee">Nazwa aplikacji</label>
        <input type="text" th:field="*{name}" id="nameeee" placeholder="Nazwa"/>
        <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}" th:errors="*{name}">Name Error</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="domain">Domena aplikacji</label>
        <input type="text" th:field="*{domain}" id="domain" placeholder="Domena"/>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Dodaj aplikację!">
</form>
```

Comment: Describe "not working" in much more detail.

Comment: What are Errors and Model? In code you provided seems everything alright.

Answer (score 0):

Problem could be conflicting dependencies. If you are using spring boot, you could just add this dependency on pom.xml file:

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId> 
</dependency>
```

Make sure you remove other hibernate or javax validation dependencies.

Also make sure you are using correct annotations. They all should be from `javax.validation.constraints.*`